# How do I run an IPA file on an iPhone/iPad simulator?

Tags: iphone, ipad

How do I run an IPA file on an iPhone/iPad simulator?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't. The ipa files are used on devices, the simulator is not a device. Not only that, but the apps for devices are built for one architecture (ARM) and the sim bins are built for another (i386).

Comment: The second point is the salient one. It's not just about intention; the simulator cannot execute the device binaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Your only way to use the simulator, is to build and run your project from Xcode.